# How to fix a not booting Ubuntu setup with encrypted root disk?

Tags: boot, luks, btrfs, cryptsetup

Ubuntu is not booting but printing weird things, either

- `/run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory`
- or `/sbin/cryptsetup not found`

then falls back to busybox after a few minutes (sometimes..).

The error appeared after moving onto a new hard disk where I had to delete an encrypted partition. After `chroot`ing into the root partition and running `udpate-initramfs -u` the error mentioned [in this Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316486/problems-with-cryptsetup-during-update) popped up:

```
cryptsetup: WARNING: could not determine root device from /etc/fstab
```

I followed the setup proposed in this article: [Full disk encryption with Ubuntu](http://thesimplecomputer.info/full-disk-encryption-with-ubuntu). Now I have a `/` btrfs volume inside LUKS with an unencrypted `/boot` partition. All this running on EFI with secure boot disabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the default hacks and fixes are putting you on a good track, however none of them was complete. This was the solution in my case:

1. Make sure the `/etc/crypttab` file is set up correctly. All entries have to refer to existing partitions. There should be
   at least one entry named "root", this is the root `/` entry. This was
   crucial for me - and nobody mentioned it so far!
2. This entry should be referred to in the `/etc/fstab` with `/dev/mapper/root`. Check
   that the UUIDs are correctly set up
3. Now run `update-initramfs -u`
   which udpates only your most recent kernel. If a cryptsetup warning
   pops up, you failed on the previous steps. Review all files and try
   figure out the problem
4. Run `update-grub` to fix any remaining grub issues
5. Now check the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Go search for the first `menuentry` which is the one that will be booted. 
   The `search`
   part should contain the UUID of the boot partition (unencrypted!).
   The `linux` part should have something saying that
   `root=/dev/mapper/root` or pointing to the UUID of the unencrypted volume (in my setup the btrfs volume)
6. Try to boot. If the lvm errors still pop up, silence them as mentioned in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/199172)

One last advice: Care for any little `warning` popping up. Usually they are meaningless, in this case they are very important.

Good luck!

Comment: I don't suppose you could add your `chroot` steps? This is not working for me.

Comment: Sure. Just replace $mount_path with the actual device you need to mount.

`sudo mount $mount_path /mnt
sudo mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev 
sudo mount -o bind /sys /mnt/sys 
sudo mount -t proc /proc /mnt/proc 
sudo cp /proc/mounts /mnt/etc/mtab 
sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf
sudo chroot /mnt`

Comment: Thanks, I eventually figured it out but hopefully this will help someone else. :)

Comment: I recently had to fix my Ubuntu 23.04 boot setup and this gist describes the steps in detail that worked for me. https://gist.github.com/bmiller59/2297db9d8df4a2fb39daceb82fe578e2

Answer (score 9):

Had a very similar issue after an update of Ubuntu 20.04 on a Dell XPS13 (2020).
Searched for hours, the solution was actually easy.

reboot and go to BIOS using "fn and F2"
BIOS > System Configuration > Sata Operation > switch to "AHCI" from "RAID On"

For some reason, this BIOS setting was switched.

Comment: You have posted this answer to several different questions saying you "had a very similar issue". I appreciate that you want to help, but I feel it would be easier for readers to judge whether to try your solution if you specified exactly what problem you had. IIRC, switching SATA mode could make some installed systems unbootable (one may have to reinstall after doing it). It is rare that an identical answer is applicable to many different questions. Please do check the details of the question carefully when answering (basic example - keys to access BIOS are hardware dependent).

Comment: I had the same issue with Dell XPS 15. The booting usually failed on trying to initialise the luks partition (“timed out waiting for device  dev-disk-by/...”).

I agree that it is a bit unintuitive advice, but it helped me a lot. At least this answer seems to have been the easiest to find with google.

Comment: This resolved my issue after my battery died on a Dell XPS 15 7590. Changing the setting back in BIOS allowed for boot to properly access and decrypt. You will get a warning that the system may become unbootable if not meant to be using AHCI, and that you may have to reinstall. So, for those giving this a shot, would be good to keep in mind in case this may not be your issue or the proper solution depending on the root cause. Everything I have is properly backed up and I configure my OS with Salt, so the risk was low in the event that I'd have to wipe. I couldn't access anyway.

Comment: For me, installing a slightly older kernel and updating grub to boot to it caused this. Thank you so much!