# cryptsetup: Waiting for encrypted source device problem

Tags: 20.04, encryption, cryptsetup

I know this has been asked before,but I don't have the technical know-how to perform any of the fixes nor do I know where to start. I turn my laptop on and it boots up to the GNU Grub whereas before it would just boot up automatically to Ubuntu then I choose Ubuntu and the statement "cryptsetup: Waiting for encrypted source device UUID=XX...." [and then it goes into the busybox shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oq9rA.jpg)
so then what would I do then?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cryptsetup: waiting for encrypted source device /swapfile, fstab empty](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254772/cryptsetup-waiting-for-encrypted-source-device-swapfile-fstab-empty)

Comment: Yes thank you :)

Answer (score 20):

I had exactly the same error message / behavior on my Dell XPS15 P56F - the issue was that the system configuration was set for SATA operation to RAID instead of AHCI. Somehow that got changed by itself, Maybe because the battery died and I didn’t use the computer for a while and hence all power supply went completely flat.

reboot and go to BIOS using "fn and F2" or "F12"
Go to ‘System Configuration’ > ‘Sata Operation’ > switch to "AHCI" from "RAID On"

The credit for this solution goes to this user: https://askubuntu.com/a/1259221

Comment: Got the `cryptsetup: waiting for encrypted source device` on a Dell XPS 9370 with ubuntu 20.04 that hadn't been booted in many months. The BIOS SATA setting had been switched to RAID. Switching it to AHCI fixed things!

Comment: Same issue for a Dell after letting the battery run out! Thanks!

Comment: This resolved my issue after my battery died on a Dell XPS 15 7590. Changing the setting back in BIOS allowed for boot to properly access and decrypt. You will get a warning that the system may become unbootable in the event that your system is not meant to be using AHCI, and that you may have to reinstall. So, for those giving this a shot, would be good to keep in mind in case this may not be your issue or the proper solution depending on the root cause.

Comment: I know comments like "Thanks" are frowned upon, but seriously - I was considering sending my laptop for repair. this hit the nail on the head. thank you.

Comment: Works like a charm for Dell Latitude 7400!

Comment: What a lifesaver. Such a tough to diagnose issue easily solved.

Comment: What the is going on. My laptaop also changed this by itself after the battery run out. Thanks.