# cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of

Tags: server, cryptsetup

I have an Problem on my Ubuntu 18.04 Rootserver.
Fresh Installation. I made an Update with

```
apt update && apt upgrade && apt dist-upgrade
```

I got this warning at the Kernel Installation.

Anyone knows how can I solve this issue?

```
sudo update-initramfs -u update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic
 cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of /dev/md1
cryptsetup: WARNING: could not determine root device from /etc/fstab
 W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/ast_dp501_fw.bin for module ast
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sdb3 I: (UUID=9055a919-6d99-49f0-88f1-7c53d6fd92a7)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
```

Comment: Same here. Saw this related question - https://askubuntu.com/questions/316486/problems-with-cryptsetup-during-update.
Although I am not sure it's exactly the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can remove you "I" message by looking in `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` file and check that the UUID noted in there is the same as your UUID of your swap-partition. You can always determine all UUIDs by running `sudo blkid` command. So, it seems in your case in `resume` file noted wrong UUID that is not matching your swap UUID. Just correct it and that info message will disappeared.

And regarding cryptsetup message. If you're not using any encryption on any of your medias, just remove `cryptsetup` package by `sudo apt remove cryptsetup` command from your system and no such message you will get ever.