# cryptsetup errors on apt-get upgrade

Tags: cryptsetup

On headless vps servers (Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS) when running

```
# apt-get upgrade
```

I get

```
cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of /dev/xvda1
cryptsetup: WARNING: could not determine root device from /etc/fstab
```

I have a single drive and a swap drive configured for these VPSes. /etc/fstab does not mention crypt anywhere for these two disks:

```
# cat /etc/fstab
/dev/xvda1 /         ext4    defaults,relatime        1 1
/dev/xvda9 swap      swap    defaults        0 0
```

Similarly

```
# lsblk -f
NAME  FSTYPE LABEL           UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
xvda9 swap                   ca251dcd-0397-4382-bce3-6b0b2ddae290 [SWAP]
xvda1 ext4   cloudimg-rootfs 6a625e34-d04d-479c-a433-2380d9f98984 /
```

I am not sure if the first answer to
[Problems with cryptsetup during update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316486/problems-with-cryptsetup-during-update) should apply, because it implies it should **not** be used if there are swap disks. I don't know anything about update-grub and I am unsure what device(s) I should grub-install.

Would it be advisable to just

```
sudo apt-get remove cryptsetup
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Do you an encrypted disk or partition or folder? Can we see `sudo lsblk -f`

Comment: Thanks, @GeorgeUdosen. I've added the results of lsblk -f to the question as requested.

Comment: Can we also see `cat /etc/crypttab`?