# update-initramfs issue

Tags: server, initramfs

Can someone explain what this error means and how i can resolve it please?

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-47-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of /dev/nvme0n1p3
cryptsetup: WARNING: could not determine root device from /etc/fstab
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/ast_dp501_fw.bin for module ast
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/nvme0n1p4
I: (UUID=868cf117-ffc8-40ae-a29e-128a42a8c1a1)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1116778/how-to-set-the-resume-variable-to-override-these-issues about fixing the RESUME variable setting.

Comment: Thanks fo rthat Terrance, I have read the post and it does seem to be answer that I will try.

Answer (score 0):

The simple explanation is that there is no error reported:  3 warnings, and 3 information lines.

cryptsetup, geberating two warnings:  If you are not using encrypted volumes, containers or swap, this can be removed from your system: [Problems with cryptsetup during update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316486/problems-with-cryptsetup-during-update)

"W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/ast_dp501_fw.bin" is annoying but can be safely ignored: https://serverfault.com/questions/755194/ubuntu-15-10-server-w-possible-missing-firmware-lib-firmware-ast-dp501-fw-bin

The "I:..." lines are informational -

- "I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/nvme0n1p4" - This indicates that if you *resume* (from hibernate) this is where the resume information comes from
- "I: (UUID=868cf117-ffc8-40ae-a29e-128a42a8c1a1)" - the UUID of the resume information (hibernation file)
- "I: Set the RESUME variable to override this." - You can change where the resume process finds it's informtion using the RESUME kernel parameter

Comment: /dev/nvme0n1p4 is listed in lsblk as [SWAP] so would it really be trying to resume from there??

Comment: @juppy8 Yes, the Debian method of implementing hibernation uses the swap file to store the hibernation data.  The file becomes similar to hiberfil.sys in Windows, but not dedicated only to the hibernation process.

Comment: @juppy8  Interestingly, if you remove swap (`sudo swapoff -a`) then Ubuntu will neither hibernate *or* sleep.  I think that if you have a small swap space, then Ubuntu may complain that there is insufficient room, depending upon the amount of RAM to be stored.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Charles. New to Linux so trying very hard to learn how to set this offsite server up. Slow process and I can only bow to those who have a greater knowledge than I. I am now thinking i should have taken the Linux route over the Winblows route many many moons ago lol

Comment: @juppy8 You and I - I hung onto Windows for a long time.  Thre's a lot to learn, and a lot that can be done.  Hibernation is a really tricky thing, and can cause issues for regular use.  I'm not at all sure that it's applicable to a server, but what do I know.  There's a reasonably good guide to hibernation at [https://askubuntu.com/questions/768136/how-can-i-hibernate-on-ubuntu-16-04/821122#821122](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768136/how-can-i-hibernate-on-ubuntu-16-04/821122#821122)